I have a problem with parametrs decorator
I want to use TSyringe to implement DI in my application. So, i use interfases, thats why i have to apply a parametrs decorator to link the interface and the class. But i have a problem "Decorators are not valid here.ts(1206)" and @injectable() for class is working without a problem.
public constructor(@inject("Controller") private _controller: Controller) { }
I used google and I tried find solution of my problem.
I changed "experimentalDecorators", "emitDecoratorMetadata" to true and "useDefineForClassFields": false, but it didn't help me.
That is my tsconfig.json:
 { "compilerOptions": { "target": "ES2020", "useDefineForClassFields": false, } "experimentalDecorators": true,  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true  }

It looks like that you have a problem with tsconfig.json.
The experimentDecorators and emitDecoratorMetadata options should be within the compilerOptions. In order to be applied correctly.
Here is the updated tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  }
}

I will be happy when this answer solves your problem.

Thank you very much, it really helps me. My problem is so foolish. It was just my inattention.
